# filter values from an array similar to SQL LIKE '%search%' using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I created an autocomplete field using JQueryUI and I've stored my data in a flat doc. I can read the values into an array... but I would like to be able to return the alphabetic matches based on the user input. So if the array contains `[orange,blue,green,red,pink,brown,black]` and the user types bl then I only return `[blue,black]`.

Looking at `array_diff()` but without complete matches on the entire value of the array, I'm not sure how to use it... maybe a regular expression thrown in? My two weakest skills array manipulation and regex Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you look at the autocomplete 'xml data parsed once' example (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#xml)? You may find it easier and more efficient to change your data storage format.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You don't need to use `array_filter` and a custom / lambda function, [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) does the trick:

```
$input = preg_quote('bl', '~'); // don't forget to quote input string!
$data = array('orange', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'pink', 'brown', 'black');

$result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $data);
```

Comment: Your answer led me to `preg_grep()`. Changed `preg_filter()` to that and removed `null` and worked like a charm; thanks!

Comment: @Ecropolis: I think the correct syntax in this case is `preg_filter('~' . $input . '~', '$0', $data);`.

Comment: This no longer works, as preg_filter has been deprecated and removed from PHP.

Comment: @AllenGingrich: You sure? I don't see that on the man page. Anyway, `preg_grep` also works, in fact I'm gonna update my answer now as it's more adequate.

Comment: @Ecropolis: Yeah, I `preg_grep` was what I meant but I made some kind of confusion with `preg_filter`... Sorry about that.

Comment: Hello, I'm using your preg_grep, but it's seem that is case sensitive, How can i use for non-case sensitive?

Comment: @EmilioGort: Sure, just add an `i` modifier after the last `~` delimiter.

Comment: How to filter those begin with the given term? I Mean: SQL LIKE 'term%' instead of '%term%'

Comment: @MichaelRopy: `$result = preg_grep('~^' . $input . '~', $data);`

Comment: Great answer. Every time this answer comes up in google when I search for array filters.

Comment: How can I get the array key for this?

Comment: @Alix Axel Will it work with multidimensional array ?

Comment: @Alix Axel Will it work with multidimensional array ? Can I search on particular key of array.

Comment: This only works with arrays where the keys is are integers

Comment: For a case insensitive search i ended up using `$result = preg_grep('/(.*)' . $input . '(.*)/i', $data);`

Answer (score 16):

[**`array_filter()`**](http://fr.php.net/array_filter), with a callback filtering function based on [**`stripos()`**](https://www.php.net/stripos), should do the trick.

For example, if the input is stored in `$input`, and your array in `$data` :

```
$input = 'bl';
$data = array('orange', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'pink', 'brown', 'black');
```

Filtering to keep only the words that contain `$input` *(no matter where in the string)* could be done this way :

```
$result = array_filter($data, function ($item) use ($input) {
    if (stripos($item, $input) !== false) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

var_dump($result);
```

And, here, you'd get :

```
array
  1 => string 'blue' (length=4)
  6 => string 'black' (length=5)
```

Changing the filtering callback, you can :

- Test if the string begins with the input -- testing if the value returned by `stripos()` is `=== 0`
- Use a case-sensitive matching function, like [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/strpos)

Comment: this is the right solution if you want to maintain key values and be able to use non integer keys

Answer (score 2):

You could simply iterate through the array to look for all strings that start with the given letters.  Having the list of words already sorted in your flat file would probably speed things up.  I think this works pretty well:

```
$input = strtolower("bl"); //from the user
$colors = array("black", "blue", "brown", "..."); //already sorted alphabetically
$matches = array();
foreach ($colors as $c){
  if (strpos($c, $input) === 0){
    //if $c starts with $input, add to matches list
    $matches[] = $c;
  } else if (strcmp($input, $c) < 0){
    //$input comes after $c in alpha order
    //since $colors is sorted, we know that we won't find any more matches
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

like %search%

```
function like(array $arr, string $patron): array
    {
        return array_filter($arr, static function (mixed $value) use ($patron): bool {
            return 1 === preg_match(sprintf('/^%s$/i', preg_replace('/(^%)|(%$)/', '.*', $patron)), $value);
        });
    }
```

test

```
$b=['a'=>'peter','b'=>'patter','c'=>'alter','d'=>'all'];
var_dump(like($b,'%ter'));// ['a'=>'peter','b'=>'patter','c'=>'alter']
var_dump(like($b,'al%'));//['c'=>'alter','d'=>'all']
```

Comment: What if the input is an array? Please help, thanks.