# regex check if array contains some words

Tags: php, regex

I have an array of matching words:

```
$search = array("lorem","dolor","sit");
```

And an array to search in:

```
 $results= array(
       "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur",
       "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation"
       "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse"
       "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident"
    );
```

Is there a regex to return **true**  where two of given words are matching?

Comment: why does it have to be regex ?

Comment: because I need to use it in a xpath compare

Comment: xpath compare() does a string to string comparison, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm using this example in my array search  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808923/filter-values-from-an-array-similar-to-sql-like-search-using-php

Answer (score 1):

You could use a word boundary `\b` in your regular expression.

> A word boundary is a position between \w and \W (non-word char), or at the beginning or end of a string if it begins or ends (respectively) with a word character.

So maybe something like this..

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
   $pattern = "/\b(" . implode('|', $search) . ")\b/i";
   $found   = preg_match_all($pattern, $result, $matches);

   if ($found) {
     print_r($matches[0]);
   }
}
```

Or you could do away with your search array and just use it as a regular expression:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
   $found = preg_match_all("/\b(?:lorem|dolor|sit)\b/i", $result, $matches);
   if ($found) {
     print_r($matches[0]);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem
    [1] => dolor
    [2] => sit
)
Array
(
    [0] => dolor
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a regex to search by this

```
$regex = '/(' . implode('|', $search) . ')/i';
```

which will be:

```
/(lorem|dolor|sit)/i
```

The `/i` makes it caseless.

You can then use the return value of `preg_match_all()` to see the number of matched words.