# How to check values of array thats starts from this string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 arrays, in this way:

```
$add[] = carblue,carred,bus;
$allad[] = car,carblue,carred,bus;
$fis[] = bus,car;
```

now i write this code:

```
foreach($add as $ad) {
   foreach($fis as $fisvalue) {
      if (in_array(substr($fisvalue, 0, strlen($ad)), $allad)) {
         echo $fisvalue;
      }
   }
}
```

But result of this code is:

```
bus
car
bus
car
bus
car
car
```

I want just `echo "bus car"` and the otherhand seems using two foreach necessary!
Can you have idea to solve my problem and echo just?:

```
car
bus
```

in other word, if value of `$allad[]` starting with `$fis[]` value echo `$fis[]` value but just once, with out repeating!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808923/filter-values-from-an-array-similar-to-sql-like-search-using-php

Comment: That code in the beginning is not valid PHP; if it's supposed to be pseudo code, is anyone's guess what it really represents. Hence we have no real idea what your array really looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, it will give you what you want.

```
<?php
$add=array('carblue','carred','bus');
$allad=array('car','carblue','carred','bus');
$fis=array('bus','car');

$outputValue = array();
foreach($add as $ad) {
    foreach($fis as $fisvalue) {
        if (in_array(substr("$fisvalue",0,strlen("$ad")),$allad)){
            $value = $fisvalue;
            if ( !in_array($value,$outputValue) )  $outputValue[] = $value;
        }
    }
}

echo implode($outputValue, ', ');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, why you need `$add` array if you want to echo `$fis` if `$allad` value starts with `$fis` value ? This code works:

```
$add = array('carblue','carred','bus');
$allad = array('car','carblue','carred','bus');
$fis = array('bus','car');

foreach($fis as $fisvalue) {

        foreach($allad as $ad) {

            if (strpos($ad,$fisvalue) === 0){             
               $matched = true;
            }
        }
        if ($matched) {
           $matched = false;
           echo $fisvalue;
        }
    }
```

first we iterate values that we want to echo once, then we compare those values with array `$allad`, if `$fisvalue` found in `$ad` at place 0 (start) then mark as matched, and if `$fisvalue` is matched then echo it

Comment: Why the `"` quotes `"` around those variables...?

Comment: What have you changed? How OP is supposed to learn from your answer?

Comment: @deceze, i just copied his solution, his pseudo code and changed a little

Comment: i need $add for strlen function to compare values.

Comment: @MAND you wrote "if value of `$allad[]` starting with `$fis[]` value echo `$fis[]` " i don't see there `$add` array

Comment: @deceze : if (in_array(substr($fisvalue, 0, strlen($ad)), $allad)) . if $ad = $fisvalue then check $allad

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$foundResults = array(); # you will save here every result you have found
foreach($add as $ad) {
   foreach($fis as $fisvalue) {
      if (in_array(substr($fisvalue, 0, strlen($ad)), $allad)) {
        if(!in_array($foundResults)) # if result doesn't exist in $foundResults, then echo result and add it to the $foundResults array
          echo $fisvalue;
          array_push($foundResults, $fisvalue);
      }
   }
}
```