# Find a string within an array (case-insensitive & search for same characters so shortform names will match)

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a way to search my array for a case-insensitive string and the string does NOT have to be exact match... for example: I want to search for "Chris" and my array has a record of "Christopher" which I want this to be a match.

So far I have tried (case-insensitive):

```
if (preg_grep( "/".$fullname."/i" , $array2 ))
```

and

```
if (in_array($fullname, $array2))
```

but no luck with either one when searching for "Chris" inside my array which contains "Christopher"

Comment: What does *no luck* mean? Do you get any errors? Please make an example with input and expected output

Comment: No error, it just doesn't find "Chris" inside my array which has "Christopher"

Comment: Please show us your **real** and **full** code! Make an example with input, output and expected output

Comment: did u try `array_filter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer given by [Alix Axel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5809221/552116)

[`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) does the trick:

```
$input = preg_quote('bl', '~'); // don't forget to quote input string!
$data = array('orange', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'pink', 'brown', 'black');

$result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $data);
```

Comment: And the difference to OP's code is, besides that it is not case insensitive ? And why do you answer the question when there is already a dupe?

Comment: Well this is just redundant to just copy an entire answer!