# Javascript or PHP Array search like SQL %seacrch%

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

Hello i'm trying to search in a Array like SQL with the "Like %search%" statement
Has anybody an idea? I need this.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: duplicated question... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808923/filter-values-from-an-array-similar-to-sql-like-search-using-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808923/filter-values-from-an-array-similar-to-sql-like-search-using-php)

Comment: there are multiple ways how to search array but it's not SQL and never will be. Without you prove what did you try or show some code we cant elp

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like it can works:

```php
function ArrayLike($search, $array)
{
  foreach ($array => $elem)
  {
    if (strstr($elem, $search) !== false)
      return (true);
  }
  return (false);
}
```

Comment: Hello it helps a bit but not at all. I like to put out the whole Array Record