# How to find array key which has value containing certain string

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I know i can do it like this when i'm looking for value inside array.

```
$example = array('example','One more example','last example');
$searchword = 'last';
$matches = array_filter($example, function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });
```

However I'm wanting to do something like this but for this example:

```
$example = array( "first" => "bar", "second" => "foo", "last example" => "boo");
$searchword = 'last';
```

How can I change this to get the key value which contains `searchword` instead of the value?

```
$matches = array_filter($example, function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });
```

Comment: you could generate an array of the array keys using array_keys and do the search on that, and use matched keys to retrieve their vals from the original array.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808923/filter-values-from-an-array-similar-to-sql-like-search-using-php)

Comment: @Michel I've already got it searching the values, I'm wanting it based on the `key`

Comment: Since PHP 5.6, if you pass `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` as the third argument of [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) it passes both the value and the key to the callback function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to use array\_filter() to filter array keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one. Here we are using `array_flip`, `array_keys` and `preg_grep`

**Solution 1:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/859246)

```
<?php
$searchword = 'last';
$example = array( "first" => "bar", "second" => "foo", "last example" => "boo");
$result=array_flip(preg_grep("/$searchword/",array_keys($example)));
print_r(array_intersect_key($example, $result));
```

**Solution 2:** (`Since PHP 5.6`) A good recommendation by @axiac

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/859260)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$searchword = 'last';
$example = array( "first" => "bar", "second" => "foo", "last example" => "boo");
$example=array_filter($example,function($value,$key) use($searchword){
    return strstr($key, $searchword);
},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
print_r($example);
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, it was easy to adapt my code to use similar code as this

Comment: @ChrisBeckett glad to help you friend.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function array_keys which get you only the key of the array $example

```
$matches = array_filter(array_keys($example), function($var) use ($searchword) { 
return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });
```

Comment: Call to undefined function `array_key()`