# PHP array search with given key word from array

Tags: php, sorting

I have a search text field, and an array I want to output below.

This is my array:

```
array=["abc","abcde","ab","abcdef"];
```

When I enter "ab" in the text field, then the list should appear. "ab" should come first.

```
ab,
abc,
abcde,
abcdef,
```

If I type "abc" then list should show:

```
abc,
abcde,
abcdef,
```

Comment: This is search by keyword from Array response please help in this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your little issue

```
<?php
$input = preg_quote('cde', '~'); // don't forget to quote input string!
$array=["abc","abcde","ab","abcdef"];
$result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $array);
foreach ($result as $val) {
    echo "$val\n";
}
?>
```

[Check this link for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808923/filter-values-from-an-array-similar-to-sql-like-search-using-php)

Comment: Thank you for your replay:-  If I search for "cde" I have to get  Below result :- abcde
abcdef But it gives me the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = ["abc","abcdeab","ab","abcdef"];
$arr = preg_grep('/cde/', $array);
sort($arr);
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

check this out