# Can we filter array values using like

Tags: php, arrays

I have list of items for example, I want my in array to give me results both on
$list1= ['apple', 'ball '];
$list2= ['apple', 'ball'];

`in_array('ball',$list1)` its okay for second case but not working for first case because there is space after ball
if return false I mean i don't want exact match but at least want this to skip spaces which are present in the array element list!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filter values from an array similar to SQL LIKE '%search%' using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808923/filter-values-from-an-array-similar-to-sql-like-search-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

`array_map` and `trim` can do the job

```
$trimmed_array = array_map('trim', $list);
print_r($trimmed_array);
```

Comment: I ma looking for its alternative `in_array('team_member',$roles) || in_array('team_member ',$roles)`